# How to do large queries over multiple tables with django

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, models

Ive been trying to work out the best way to implement this query for awhile now but haven't had much look

I have a very basic user following table..

```
class followTable(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   taget_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to be able to get all the users(target_user) that the current user is following then return all posts from another table that belong to the target_user, what would be the best way?

Ive tried

```
userlist = followTable.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

then doing a foreach on the userlist and querying each user individually but that seems a bit messy, has any one got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post.objects.filter(
    author__in=followTable.objects.filter(user=MY_USER).values_list('target_user', flat=True))
```

Comment: Instead of `[x.target_user for x in followTable.objects.filter(user=MY_USER)]` , using `FollowTable.objects.filter(user=MY_USER).values_list('target_user', flat=True)` will be a better approach

Comment: @FallenAngel, I like that. Thanks!